# Trying to split a string and apply alternate suffixes

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a string:

```
str='SA201406005/007/009/010'
```

how to get this result?

```
['SA201406005','SA201406007','SA201406009', 'SA201406010']
```

This code works:

```
arr=[]
arr=str.split(/\//)
arr=arr[1..-1].map{|x|x=arr[0].slice(0,arr[0].size-arr[-1].size)+x}.unshift(arr[0])
```

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What's about the `010`. What is the rule there that it should not be in the result?

Comment: @spickermann The code in the question does include the _010_ string in the result.  It seems like a simple goof, so I corrected the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = str.split("/")
a.map{|s| s.rjust(a.first.length, a.first)}
# => ["SA201406005", "SA201406007", "SA201406009", "SA201406010"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This code makes no assumptions about the length of either the base or any of its suffixes:

```
def apply_suffixes(s)
  base, *suffixes = s.split("/")
  [base] + suffixes.map do |suffix|  
    base[0...-suffix.length] + suffix
  end
end

p apply_suffixes("SA201406005/007/009/010")
# => ["SA201406005", "SA201406007", "SA201406009", "SA201406010"]
```

One interesting part is:

```
  base, *suffixes = s.split("/")
```

Which uses [destructuring bind](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html).

Also interesting:

```
  0...-suffix.length
```

The "..." operater productes a range which excludes its maximum.  `0...-suffix.length` is equivalent to `0..(-suffix.length-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
str = 'SA201406005/007/009/010'
prefix, suffixes = str[0..7], str[8..-1]
suffixes.split('/').map { |s| prefix + s }
# => ["SA201406005", "SA201406007", "SA201406009", "SA201406010"]
```

It assumes that the prefix is always 8 characters.

Comment: what does str[8..-1] means as I understood it will start character from 8 but what does -1 means?

Comment: String indexes wrap in ruby. So if `[0]` is `S`, then `[-1]` would be `0`. It means the end of the string.